# jQuery Masked Input - Existing Input Value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask

I am using jQuery masked input plugin. However when I set the mask, any existing value in the input field is being destroyed.  Doing the following:

```
$(".priceSKUID").mask("**-***-******", { placeholder: " " });
```

There must be a way to deal with existing values which are programmatically placed into the input field.

Comment: Masked Input is a little limited and bugged. Can you try [meioMask](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/)? Is very similar.

Answer (score 3):

When you set a mask like 9999, the value of the input has to be 9999. But, if we have a mask with some optional characters like 9?999, it means that if the value have just one character, it will be displayed. In other words, the last three characters are opitional. I just tried it and works fine.

Answer (score 3):

$('#my').mask('99.99').val('25.00') is not working

It should have trigger('input')

```
$('#my').mask('99.99').val('25.00').trigger('input')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it vía javascript after calling

```
<input id='my' />

...

$('#my').mask('99.99').val('25.00')
```

You must honor the mask format by setting the value this way. Its not that simple but is the only way i found to achieve this goal.